# How to exclude header when writing data to CSV

Tags: c#, winforms, csvhelper

I am writing my data from a `public class` to a CSV file. As I want to append my data, I want to exclude the importing of header and only import the data from the class. My code below imports both headers and data. Hope to get help. Thanks.

**Record.cs - my class**

```
public class Record
{
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs - my form**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Record> records;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        records = new List<Record>();
    }

    private void Savetocsv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myDocument = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(myDocument + "/my-data.csv", append: true))
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
            {
                csv.WriteRecords(records);
            }                
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is CsvWriter?

Comment: @RistoM. Hi, it is a feature that helps to write data to CSV. This feature is available when the program is using CSVHelper that can be installed as a NuGet package.

Comment: With the writer configuration you should be able to say if you want headers or not https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/IWriterConfiguration/

Comment: Or Simply loop on records and WriteRecord without the S. This one don't do headers.

Answer (score 12):

Using the [`Configuration`](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/Configuration/) , you can use the property `HasHeaderRecord`:

> `HasHeaderRecord` : 
>   Gets or sets a value indicating if the CSV file has a header record.
>   Default is true.

```
var records = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "one" },
    new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "one" },
};

using (var writer = new StreamWriter($"file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, new Configuration { HasHeaderRecord = false }))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(records);
}
```

Result file : "file.csv"

> 1;one
>   1;one

Or simply loop on records an write them:

```
var records = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "one" },
    new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "one" }
};

using (var writer = new StreamWriter($"file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
{
    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        csv.WriteRecord(record);
        csv.NextRecord();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The name of the configuration class has changed.

```
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(outputStream, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    HasHeaderRecord = false
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your writing method as following and then [CsvHelper.WriterConfiguration](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/IWriterConfiguration/) do the trick (note *HasHeaderRecord*):

```
private void Savetocsv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myDocument = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(myDocument + "/my-data.csv", append: true))
    {
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, new Configuration { HasHeaderRecord = false }))
        {
            csv.WriteRecords(records);
        }                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which CsvWriter you are using, but the one [here](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/5197/writing-csv-files-using-c) has a `HasHeaderRecord` property that you can use to ignore or include headers.

```
private void Savetocsv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myDocument = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(myDocument + "/my-data.csv", append: true))
    {
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
        {
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
            csv.WriteRecords(records);
        }               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first row from `records` before calling:

```
csv.WriteRecords(records);
```

(If you need to leave records unchanged, add the headers back again after calling WriteRecords(...).)

```
private void Savetocsv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myDocument = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(myDocument + "/my-data.csv", append: true))
    {
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
        {
            records.RemoveAt(0);  // Removes the header row.
            csv.WriteRecords(records);
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Your answer would remove the first data but not the header. So if I were to have two sets of data, the CSV file would print out the header and the second set of data.

Comment: I added a second answer which I hope will be more helpful.