# How to remove Header from a CSV FileStream

Tags: c#, file-handling, csvhelper

I have to work on a certain set of limitations for csv file upload :

- I will be working with 'large' CSV files (containing header row)
- I need to remove the first header row from the CSV file
- The file-upload code needs a **FileStream (not containing the header)** as input! (as I am restricted to do a lot of stream operations on top of this stream (containing headerless csv data))

Wrapper C# Code :

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("C:\~~~\~~~\~~~\SampleFile.csv"))
{
    //CSV Header removal snippet - which gives me a new stream containing data without headers.
    ~
    ~
    ~
    ~
    //All my stream handling code of chunking stream into 100mb and then uploading each chunk to azure storage (which is not part of this question)
}
```

Now I already know - that I can simply remove headers of a csv file using libraries like - `CSVHelper` 
 ([How to exclude header when writing data to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55332538/how-to-exclude-header-when-writing-data-to-csv))

Using the above way I can create a header-less copy of a file and read the new file back as FileStream - but the problem is that I'm dealing with large files and making a copy of a file just to remove headers will be a space-consuming job.

So for the first time - I am asking a question in StackOverflow - to find a good solution to the above problem. I hope I was able to explain the problem clearly.

Comment: Use StreamReader and then ReadLine() to remove first line.

Comment: So I can take the stream and pass it to the stream reader - then do readline() but then - will the original 'stream' object have no headers ?

Comment: ReadLine() method gives the first line - but that's messing up the stream's.position, I want my stream's position to just move till the end of header row

Comment: Is the end of the header row before of after the return at the end of the line?  Every line in a CSV file has a return at the end of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work to seek to the end of the first line.

```cs
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("~~filepath~~"))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))                
{
    string line = null;
    if ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {        
        stream.Position = line.Length + 2;
        // The 2 is for NewLine(\r\n)
    }

    //All my stream handling code of chunking stream into 100mb and then uploading each chunk to azure storage (which is not part of this question)   
}
```

Comment: so I got my answer, by doing line.length + 2, so I'll mark your answer as the right answer, however I found that you don't have to read the file 2 times.

Comment: you can simply read the stream, use it in the reader and then in the if condition set stream.position = offset... that will be good for large file handling..